# how to remove local isDirty objects from ember-data before loading a template?

Tags: rest, ember.js, save, ember-data

I am have a `/customers`. I am creating a new customer as :

```
    var new_customer = this.store.createRecord('customer', customer_object);
    new_customer.save().then(onSuccess, onError);
```

where `customer_object` contains a record for customer. When customer is created successfully, `onSuccess` gets called which then transit to newly created customer (`/customers/<new_customer>`). This flow is working as expected. When I get an error (say Unauthorized Access), `onError` is also getting called which then transit to `/customers` after showing an error-alert. The problem here is that, though the customer is not created at server-side, when I transit to `/customers`, it shows that newly created customer (with `isDirty` as true.) How can I remove such invalid objects from my local ember-array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
new_customer.deleteRecord();
```

in `onError` handler to remove the record after error has occured.

Comment: Thanks it worked ! So does that mean `deleteRecord()` removes isDirty objects from the local array? (unlike destroyRecord() which calls http DELETE on /products)

Comment: This method will delete the record from local store. Because the entity was never saved on the server, deleting it from the store will remove it also from isDirty objects.